# Ctrl + ' (single quote) does not send a key sequence on keydown, and VSCode can't toggle line comment

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-events, hotkeys, keyboard-layout

I am trying to toggle line comment in VSCode, but the command isn't working. When the keyboard layout on Windows is Norwegian QWERTY, then the keyboard shortcut is mapped to `ctrl`+`'` (or `ctrl+oem_2`). When trying to assign the keyboard shortcut manually, i figured out that the `'` key is not being registered when it is pressed in combination with the `ctrl` key.

When running the command `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` according to the [keybinding troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues), and i press `ctrl`+`'` i see this output:

```
2023-11-07 10:46:12.931 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-11-07 10:46:12.931 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2023-11-07 10:46:12.931 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
2023-11-07 10:46:12.931 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
2023-11-07 10:46:12.931 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2023-11-07 10:46:13.551 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
```

This output suggests that VSCode does not register the `'` key in the combo. This is not a VSCode specific issue, as i can see the same behavior at https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html

[image]

Here we can see that there is no keydown event created for the `'` key, and according to the [keybinding troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues), if VSCode doesn't receive a good key combination, i have to configure my OS or drivers to release that key combination to applications.

The `ctrl`+`k` `ctrl`+`c` shortcut works to add a comment and i know i can assign the toggleLineComment command to another shortcut, but it would be best to use the same shortcut across layouts, and that this can be done with a single shortcut instead of multiple chords.

How can I configure Windows, my drivers or my keyboard layout to send a keydown event for `'` when `ctrl`+`'` is pressed?

Comment: This seems to also be the case for other keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had 1Password application installed, and when going to Settings > General > "Autofill:" it was mapped to `ctrl`+`\`. Removing this mapping fixed the issue.

1Password says that this is a known issue. They don't know when this will be fixed, but you should keep an eye on the [1Password Releases](https://releases.1password.com/) page to see if this is fixed.

Comment: Interesting problem. Have you found it by chance, or did you use some other system-wide keyboard troubleshooting utility? Also, it seems like a bug on the 1Password side: one would expect to either pass the captured keyboard input in context where it would not do anything, or at leas show some notification such as "You have invoked autofill, but there is no field in the active window to be filled" or something like that. Have you looked for a bugreport / feature request for that?

Comment: @myf I found this by chance as I noticed the pin code window opened to unlock 1Password. I don't have a global keyboard troubleshooting utility.

I have contacted 1Password through their feedback form and they said that this is a known issue. I have updated my answer with info i have gotten from 1Password.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem to be 1Password Desktop App in Windows shortcut with Ctrl + \ which conflicts with the VS code.

I disabled the "Autofill" an cleared the shortcut.

Comment: NIce, thanks for your answer! However this is already included in the accepted answer. If you have additional info or there is something wrong with the existing answer, you can add a comment. If the accepted answer helped you, please add an upvote!